# Placing models on the terrain

Tags: cesiumjs

I'm trying to place my 3d models on the terrain. I have followed the [Sample Terrain tutorial](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Terrain.html&label=Showcases). Terrainprovider provides the height of the coordinates but when I try to place my model on the ground, it doesn't always sit on the ground . For some coordinates model appears in the air. (for example: longitude: 96.12, latitude: 22.02). How can I solve this problem? Is there anyway to place models to the surface of the terrain?

If it is not clear, I  can post my code but it's very similar to sample terrain tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved this problem by using a ray.

```
  let rayPos = new Cesium.Cartographic(pos.longitude, pos.latitude, pos.height + 100);
  let rayCartesianPos = ellipsoid.cartographicToCartesian(rayPos);
  let ray = new Cesium.Ray(rayCartesianPos, Cesium.Cartesian3.negate(rayCartesianPos, new Cesium.Cartesian3()));   
  let newCoords = viewer.scene.globe.pick(ray, viewer.scene);
```